# Roslyn CodeFix - MSBuild Properties/metadata and Unit testing

Tags: roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis, microsoft.codeanalysis

I'm building a roslyn analyzer/code fix but I wan't to access the MSBuild Properties and metadata (both from Directory.build.props and the .csproj) in order to know how to apply the code fix. I only found documentation to do it in source generators but not for analyzers.

To be more specific I want to know if the project is configured to use the new ImplicitUsings, but it would be usefull to also have access to everything.

Also do we have any way to get all the project global usings?

And using the new Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Testing how can I add the MSBuild property so I can actually test it?

Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accessing *MSBuild* properties and metadata in `DiagnosticAnalyzer`s is actually quite similar to how they're read and tested in `ISourceGenerator`s/`IIncrementalGenerator`s, since *Source Generators* are technically *.NET analyzers* as well.

I assume that the documentation you've mentioned is the [Source Generators Cookbook](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/docs/features/source-generators.cookbook.md).

First, we need to make the *MSBuild* property available to the global analyzer config options of the analyzer:

```xml
<Project>
  <ItemGroup>
    <CompilerVisibleProperty Include="MyAnalyzer_MyProperty" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Then, we may read the value of that property from the [AnalyzerConfigOptionsProvider](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/src/Compilers/Core/Portable/DiagnosticAnalyzer/AnalyzerConfigOptionsProvider.cs)'s `GlobalOptions`. You'll find it within the parameter of the `AnalysisContext.Register*` method of your choice that you use within your overridden `DiagnosticAnalyzer.Initialize(AnalysisContext)` method.
For example `RegisterCompilationAction`:

```cs
bool isEnabled = false;
if (compilationAnalysisContext.Options.AnalyzerConfigOptionsProvider.GlobalOptions.TryGetValue("build_property.MyAnalyzer_MyProperty", out string? value))
{
    isEnabled = value.Equals("true", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || value.Equals("enable", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
}

ImmutableDictionary<string, string?>.Builder properties = ImmutableDictionary.CreateBuilder<string, string?>();
if (isEnabled)
{
    properties.Add("IsEnabled", value);
}

var diagnostic = Diagnostic.Create(Rule, location, properties.ToImmutable());
compilationAnalysisContext.ReportDiagnostic(diagnostic);
```

The `CodeFixProvider`'s `CodeFixContext` does not have a dedicated `AnalyzerOptions Options` property, but you may pass the value via the `Diagnostic.Properties`:

```cs
foreach (Diagnostic diagnostic in context.Diagnostics)
{
    if (diagnostic.Properties.TryGetValue("IsEnabled", out string? value))
    {
        var action = CodeAction.Create(Title, cancellationToken => OnCreateChangedDocument(context.Document, cancellationToken), diagnostic.Id);
        context.RegisterCodeFix(action, diagnostic);
    }
}
```

... or, what I just discovered while composing this answer, access the `AnalyzerConfigOptionsProvider` through `CodeFixContext.Document.Project.AnalyzerOptions`. This works wherever you have a `Document` (or `Project`) available:

```cs
public override Task RegisterCodeFixesAsync(CodeFixContext context)
{
    bool hasValue = context.Document.Project.AnalyzerOptions.AnalyzerConfigOptionsProvider.GlobalOptions.TryGetValue("build_property.MyAnalyzer_MyProperty", out string? value);
}
```

Additionally, it works with `CodeRefactoringProvider`:

```cs
public override Task ComputeRefactoringsAsync(CodeRefactoringContext context)
{
    bool hasValue = context.Document.Project.AnalyzerOptions.AnalyzerConfigOptionsProvider.GlobalOptions.TryGetValue("build_property.MyAnalyzer_MyProperty", out string? value);

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

... and with `CompletionProvider`:

```cs
public override Task ProvideCompletionsAsync(CompletionContext context)
{
    bool hasValue = context.Document.Project.AnalyzerOptions.AnalyzerConfigOptionsProvider.GlobalOptions.TryGetValue("build_property.MyAnalyzer_MyProperty", out string? value);

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

... and also with `DiagnosticSuppressor`:

```cs
public override void ReportSuppressions(SuppressionAnalysisContext context)
{
    bool hasValue = context.Options.AnalyzerConfigOptionsProvider.GlobalOptions.TryGetValue("build_property.MyAnalyzer_MyProperty", out string? value);
}
```

And for testing via [Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Testing](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-sdk/tree/main/src/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Testing), you can add the global analyzer config option via `ProjectState.AnalyzerConfigFiles` of the `AnalyzerTest<TVerifier>`'s `SolutionState TestState` property:

```cs
string config = $"is_global = true{Environment.NewLine}build_property.MyAnalyzer_MyProperty = {true}";
analyzerTest.TestState.AnalyzerConfigFiles.Add(("/.globalconfig", config));
```

Above I described the usage with the custom MSBuild property `MyAnalyzer_MyProperty`, but of course it works with the well-known `ImplicitUsings` property too.

Comment: The blogpost describes that using a .props file and including it in the nuget build makes it possible for the project that is using the analyzer to only add the property in a property group. But this is not working, I always have to include the CompilerVisibleProperty in the project using the analyzer aswell @FlashOver

Comment: I figured it out. In my case, I had to add $(AssemblyName).props in the include string

Comment: @FlashOver wow thats funny, im actually watching your vid and im just seeing your name now.. I still didnt get this to work sadly